# Show that $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) = \min(\text{ord}_{z_0}(f),\text{ord}_{z_0}(g))$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be analytic functions defined on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, and let $z_0 \in U$. Let $n= \text{ord}_{z_0}(f)$ and $m=\text{ord}_{z_0}(g)$. Suppose that $n<m$. Show that $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) = \min(n,m)$.

Here's what I have so far:

Clearly $\min(n,m) = n$ in this case, so we wish to show that $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) = n$. We know that we can write $f(z)=(z-z_0)^n h_1(z)$ and $g(z)=(z-z_0)^m h_2(z)$ for some $h_1,h_2$ such that these functions are analytic and $h_1(z_0), h_2(z_0) \neq 0$.

Since $n<m$, we have
$$\begin{align} (f+g)(z) &= (z-z_0)^n h_1(z) + (z-z_0)^m h_2(z) \\
            &> (z-z_0)^n h_1(z) + (z-z_0)^n h_2(z) \\
&= (z-z_0)^n (h_1(z)+h_2(z)). \end{align} $$

But this would seem to imply that $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) > n = \min(n,m)$.

Any help as to where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing an inequality into your computation is unlikely to lead to a correct result, since you are trying to prove equality. Try this:
$$(f+g)(z) = (z-z_0)^n h_1(z) + (z-z_0)^m h_2(z) 
           = (z-z_0)^n (h_1(z) + (z-z_0)^{m-n} h_2(z)).
$$
Then show that the second term on the RHS cannot vanish at $z=z_0$.