# order of zero of $f+g$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have two analytic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ defined on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, and let $z_0 \in U$. Let $n= \text{ord}_{z_0}(f)$ and $m=\text{ord}_{z_0}(g)$. Suppose that $n<m$. I am asked to give an example of an $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ such that $n=m$ but $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) \geq \min(n,m)$.

This question is related to this one: [Show that $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) = \min(\text{ord}_{z_0}(f),\text{ord}_{z_0}(g))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017404/show-that-textord-z-0fg-min-textord-z-0f-textord-z-0g).

Someone has given an answer to that question, but I am still confused. I get why $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g) = \min(n,m)$, but how can $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g)$ be strictly greater than the smaller of $m$ and $n$? It seems to be that it should be either $m$ or $n$, because for $n<m$ you can factor $f+g$ as $(z-z_{0})^n (h(z) +(z-z_{0})^{m-n} k(z))$ (or you could switch $m,n$ if $m<n$. ) But when would the $\text{ord}_{z_0}(f+g)$ be strictly bigger than the smaller one of $m,n$?

Can someone help please?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have the same order, $f(z)=(z-z_0)^nh(z)$, $g(z)=(z-z_0)^nk(z)$, then $f(z)+g(z)=(z-z_0)^n(h(z)+k(z))$, it is possible that $h(z_0)+k(z_0)=0$, so $h(z)+k(z)$ has order at least $1$, and $f(z)+g(z)$ has order greater than the order of $f(z)$ or $g(z)$ alone.

Comment: For a concrete example, consider $z_0=0$ and $f(z)=z^n(z^k-1)$ and $g(z)=z^n(z^k+1)$.